# History of commands with user

Tags: shell

Can i know who all the users have executed which command on a machine?

Answer (score 1):

On a Unix-type machine, you would have to enable process accounting.  The kernel would then write a record for each process that terminates indicating which command was executed, by whom, when, and how long it took to a file.  You could then analyze the file.

The Linux [HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Process-Accounting/) was updated in 2001 - it is likely to apply still, but you will need to check.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft world that would be audit (entries in the security event log).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751315.aspx

See the Process Tracking section.